# Compound Inequality to Absolute Value assumption in Epsilon-Delta problem

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

In a specific part of the solution to an $\varepsilon - \delta$ limit problem (substituting for some number $k$ one of the factors of the quadratic to find $\delta$ correspondence), the author establishes that

$-3<x-1<-1$ , therefore $|x-1|<3$

He supports it with the following comment:

"The smallest x can be is -1.9999..., and that number minus 1 is -2.9999..., which is less than 3.

I'm trying to wrap my head around how he establishes equivalency between that inequality and that absolute value, and the supporting comment confuses me even more. What I'm trying to understand is what he's doing or how to properly go from a compound inequality into an absolute value, and to do so in a way that allows me to apply whatever technique he used there on other problems that require me to do so.

If it helps in any way, the problem is as follows:

*Identify a value of $\delta$ (accurate to two decimal places) that corresponds to $\varepsilon = 0.01$ given $\lim_{x \to -1}(x^2+3)=4$, according to the definition of limits*

**edit: spelling and readability**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well $-1 < 3$ right? Therefore $-3 < x-1 < -1 < 3$. That is to say $-3 < x-1 <3$ which is equivalent to $|x-1| <3$.

The justification the author is making is confusing and unnecessary, it's much simpler than that.

**edit:** Its a known property of absolute values that  $|x-a|<b  \Leftarrow \Rightarrow -b<x-a<+b$

Comment: Thank you so very much! This author is usually very on point with his intuitive guiding comments, this time I guess he wasn't, and I was thrown clear off! I am very familiar with the property, but somehow couldn't make the connection. Thank you once again!